# Есть ли смысл обрезать фото на сервере?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, веб-сервер

К примеру есть некий товар, у него краткое описание(предпросмотр) и полное описание, в котором большое фото и превью к каждому из них(слайдер с миниатюрами).

Итого каждое фото товара нам нужно иметь в трех вариантах в данном примере. И дело нестолько в обрезке, сколько в том что нам нужно отдать 3 разных размера одного фото с сервера, а это 3 запроса. Самое интересное что общий размер этих фото может быть в итоге больше самого оригинала :)

Возникает вопрос - а не проще ли отдать одно фото и ресайзить его на клиенте с помощью того же CSS или JS ? Отдаем одно фото для одного товара вместо трех, а нормальный браузер его закеширует и все. Дальше делаем с ним что хотим. Насколько я понял такой подход использует сейчас к примеру Twitter.

Интересно узнать кто что думает по этому поводу.

Comment: интересный вопрос на самом деле. аспектов куча. плюсанул

Comment: Уточните первую фразу, особенно участок: "...в котором большое фото и превью к каждому из них(слайдер с миниатюрами).". Теряется суть что чьим является превью, и откуда берется 3 варианта фото.

Comment: Зашли в каталог товаров(грид к примеру если так понятнее) - там превьюшка товара - первый вариант 100х100 к примеру, открыли карточку товара(полное описание с размерами и т.д.), в нем слайдер - превью к примеру 150х150 и само фото в слайдере 300х350. Плюс незабываем что при клике может еще захотим показать оригинал. Итого 4 варианта одного фото. Размеры взяты произвольно для примера.

Comment: Я бы в таком случае хранил бы 2 варианта: 100 на 100, потому что зачем грузить много больших изображений в каталог, а в саму карточку уже грузил бы большие изображения (хотя вариант 100х100 и 150х150 можно объединить в один для экономии). А по хорошему, собрал бы статистику по кликам на картинки, чтобы знать чем можно принебречь. Если народ не смотрит большие картинки, то сделать превьюшки (100 на 100) и уменьшить тем самым трафик. Как мне кажется в этом вопросе стоит плясать от нагрузки на сервер (место) и скорости загрузки страницы (по правилу не грузи то, что не надо)

Comment: Есть ещё промежуточный вариант: храним на сервере единственный оригинал, а обрезаем-уменьшаем на лету по запросу от клиента. Так YouTube делает, например. Но для этого нужен относительно мощный сервер, чтоб обрезал-уменьшал быстро (и кэшировать не забывать)

Comment: **teran**, спасибо. **andreymal**, так в итоге же тоже куча запросов :) @Sergey Glazirin да, тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту - миниатюра плюс оригинал. Т.е. только два варианта. Хотя ради интереса посмотрю что будет если оcтавить одно фото. На кол-ве запросов это явно должно хорошо отразиться, насчет скорости загрузки неуверен, а вот на трафике пользователей, хотя...мой коммент ниже по этому поводу :)

Answer (score 3):

Конечно их нужно обрезать (масштабировать).

Зальют вам фотографии по 10 мегабайт, а потом пользователь откроет с мобильника страницу со списком из 100 товаров.

Лучше потратить место на сервере, чем трафик посетителей.

Comment: Так никто не мешает ограничить заливаемый файл скажем до 1мб. Качество ужать, если это jpg к примеру, процентов до 70-75. Давайте откровенно, меня будет намного больше волновать мой сервер и его ресурсы, чем то сколько трафика израсходует пользователь. Видео на мобильных устройствах как-то смотрят ведь :) Так что здесь вопрос скорее не в трафике, в кол-ве запросов, и следовательно процессорном времени. Просто представьте 3 запроса на 1000 пользователей = 3 тысячи запросов, а если фото одно, тогда 1000. Итого 3 vs 1 тысяча запросов, и это если 1000 посетителей, а если их сотни тысяч ?